# Calculate the Convex Hull of Clustered Centers from K-means Numpy Array

Tags: python, scipy, k-means, data-science, convex-hull

I have a Numpy array of colors that is returned when using K-means quantization on an image. After K-means is used, I need to take those centers and calculate the convex hull of the set of color centers.

Essentially I need to find which points/colors don't have enough contrast from another color. I think the answer to this would be to find the points inside the hull (simplices?) that aren't the vertices of the hull.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image   
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
from skimage import color, exposure
from sklearn import cluster

def quantize(pixels, n_colors):
    width, height, depth = pixels.shape
    reshaped_pixels = np.reshape(pixels, (width * height, depth))
    model = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=n_colors, n_init=100, precompute_distances=True)
    labels = model.fit_predict(reshaped_pixels)
    centers = model.cluster_centers_
    quantized_pixels = np.reshape(centers[labels], (width, height, centers.shape[1]))

    return quantized_pixels, centers, labels

def scale_image(img, max_width=100):
    img_width, img_height = img.size
    ratio = (max_width / float(img_width))
    new_height = int((float(img_height)*float(ratio)))
    img.thumbnail((max_width, new_height), Image.NEAREST)
    return img

# Open image, convert to RGB just in case
img = Image.open('image2.jpg').convert('RGB')

# Scale image to speed up processing
img = scale_image(img, 80)

# Convert to numpy array
np_img_array = np.array(img)

# Convert rgb to lab colorspace
lab_pixels = color.rgb2lab(np_img_array)

# Kmeans quantization
quantized_lab_pixels, centers, labels = quantize(lab_pixels, 16)

# Convert pixels back to rgb
quantized_rgb_pixels = (color.lab2rgb(quantized_lab_pixels)*255).astype('uint8')

# Attempt to use convex hull around cluster centers
hull = ConvexHull(centers)

for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(centers[simplex, 0], centers[simplex, 1])
plt.scatter(*centers.T, alpha=.5, color='k', marker='v')


for p in centers:
    point_is_in_hull = point_in_hull(p, hull)
    marker = 'x' if point_is_in_hull else 'd'
    color = 'g' if point_is_in_hull else 'm'
    plt.scatter(p[0], p[1], marker=marker, color=color)

plt.show()
```

**Update:** Here is my rendered plot output. I'm not using the color labels in the plotting in this render.

[image]

Here is more so what would be helpful to see. However, the plots aren't what I need... I need to find out which of the cluster centers (colors) make up the vertices of the hull and then pair them back to the vertices labels.

[image]

Here is an example of the RGB colors outputted (on the left), and then on the right you would have the final colors, which would be after excluding cluster centers that fall outside of the region.

[image]

Comment: Can you add to your code a sample output of your code, and also what the desired output would be?

Comment: @user8153 I'll try... but not really sure how to go about that since I'm not getting the correct outputs to start with. It's more so about finding which clusters are not within the hull region... and that would be the answer.

Comment: Could you please clarify: you want to "find out which of the cluster centers are not within the convex hull" -- the convex hull of what? The convex hull of the cluster centers?

Comment: @user8153 yes that is correct. These cluster centers are actual colors. Sometimes the cluster centers are very similar colors, but I need to exclude the very similar colors based on contrast to the rest of the cluster centers. I was thinking that if I used each of the centers to draw the regions then it would potentially exclude clusters that didn't have enough contrast between them.

Comment: Just updated the question with another image to show sample output and desired output.

Comment: Why doesn't every cluster center lie within the convex hull of the the cluster centers? Doesn't the convex hull of a set of points include all those points?

Comment: After thinking more, I believe you're right. I think the answer is to find the points inside the hull... the points that are masked. The edge points (points that make up the hull mask) are the points that will be used in the final output.

Comment: If your cluster centers are too similar, you should try using fewer clusters or change your distance measure so it uses contrast instead of euclidean distance along lab colorspace.

Comment: @swenzel I don't see either one of those solving the problem in a precise way. Both of those suggestions will leave the door open for other problems. If you calculate based only on contrast, then you're not going to effectively cluster the colors...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really know what I was talking about when I mentioned contrast. I've read a little about colorcoding now and understand that contrast doesn't take into account the color itself but only relative luminance. I meant you need a distance measure, that has the same idea of similarity which you have. Apparently you consider colors similar which the clustering algorithm considers different. So change the distance measure, play around with it, make luminance count a little less for example.